# try and if - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, if-statement, local-variables

I tried run this code but I have an error:

> a4  local variable referenced before assignment

```
a1 = '/fr/store/a'
try:
   a2 = '/fr/store/b/collection/3432'
   a2_store = "store"
   a3 = a2.split ("store/")
   a4 = a3[0]
   if a2_store in a2:
      print ('a2')
except:
   if a4 not in a1:
      print ('a1')
```

Comment: I didn't get an error running your code. I got `a2` printed. Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's part of the problem, but a [bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948581/4518341). Try switching it to `except IndexError` and see if the issue continues.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is raised before `a4 = a3[0]` is executed (for example, if `a3[0]` raises an `IndexError`), then `a4` is, indeed, not defined.

Comment: The example is self-contained actually, and there's no error when you run it

Comment: Oh but an exception could come from elsewhere, like a KeyboardInterrupt, since they're using a bare `except`. hmm...